# Why do we have an edit grace period?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

As I see it the purpose of the "grace period" (the period of time when you may edit your question/answer without said edit showing up in the reivision history) is to either:

1. Reduce the clutter in the SO database so multiple minor edits don't show up as "expensive" versions.
2. Give the OP an opportunity to fix their post so that their original error doesn't show up in the edit history.

I think reason 2) is ridiculous.  If you screwed up, oh well, no big deal, but your mistake should show up in the edit history.

I think reason 1) is dubious.  I'm sure there is a cost associated with a new version, but I doubt it is significant in the grand scheme of things. (the vast amount of other persistent edits that occur)

I think having a grace period is unhelpful and is often brazenly counter-productive for understanding what a conversation around a question is about.  Consider this question:

[Why isn't this static c# variable changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421383/why-isnt-this-static-c-sharp-variable-changing)

The first several comments are, "What static variables?", "No static variables are visible", and "The clue is in the name static. You have to declare your variable as static. You haven't."  Coming two hours later, I see that the fields are in fact declared static.  Moreover, there is nothing in the edit history to suggest that the OP ever asked the question otherwise.  I can only assume that the reason for this disconnect is that the question was initially delivered with code that did not declare `static` fields.  However, presumably the grace period interfered and did not allow any evidence for this state to persist.

Do we really need a grace period?  In my experience over the years, the existence of a grace period has *always* been harmful.  If SO can bear the expense, I feel the "feature" should be discarded.

Comment: This *is* the example.  It's harmful because I could not make heads or tails of what the comments are about.  I was forced to surmise.  And while we *all* agree comments imply no lasting value, they are -- clearly by virtue of their existence -- of *some* value, and I usually take it to mean that their value is *especially* pronounced when trying to tease out the meaning of a particular question.  When the edit history is lost, it becomes needlessly difficult to divine the parameters of the discussion -- a discussion warranted to determine a way to help the OP.

Comment: @pnuts, I mean no disrespect, but I think your comment is trite.  Yes, questions should stand alone.  To that end, ideally no comments should ever be necessary to help the person posing the question fashion it in a way that will be most helpful to future visitors.  But I'm *sure* you'll agree, comments are often necessary.  Sometimes they don't help and the question is unsalvageable.  But sometimes they do in fact help.

Comment: @pnuts, that's fair, and I agree.  But that is a non-sequitor.  As far as this question was concerned, I came into it without any of your legitimate suggestions having taken place.  Thus the merit of those suggestions cannot bear fruit until someone who has observed the discussion has edited the question as you had advised.  Thus my original point that the lost edit history has caused problems remains valid:  if the edit history had been preserved, I would have been left a *far* better position to be that very editor.

Answer (score 44):

It's #2. The UI simplification is a nice bonus - I've yet to see a revision history for trivial edits that wasn't unbearably frustrating - but #2 was the original design goal for this feature, and was considered critically important even in the very, very early days.

Why? Because these mistakes are *extremely common*.

Anecdotally, everyone seems to be familiar with that moment when you hit "submit" and suddenly notice a typo, spelling error, or paragraph you completely forgot to finish. It's the online equivalent of [Rich Hall's ignisecond](http://iheartquotes.com/fortune/show/ignisecond_n_1) - a depressing reminder of your own fallibility. It's the inspiration behind Gmail's "undo send" feature and similar "quick edit" functions on countless forums.

In concrete terms, something like 20% of answers are edited at least once during the grace period. That's a *lot* of igniseconds.

> I think reason 2) is ridiculous. If you screwed up, oh well, no big deal, but your mistake should show up in the edit history.

Why?

Everyone makes mistakes. Good software recognizes this and makes recovery painless; bad software rubs every error in your face. On a site where posts can remain visible and useful for *years*, why is it important to hang on to trivial mistakes that were fixed within minutes?

Comment: Too slow, @Astro - I'd already edited it twice by the time you got there.

Comment: For "Why?" - so that the OP's mistake doesn't end up looking like *others* weren't reading properly. This happens really frequently. Maybe we don't need the full details of the original post - but just a note saying "This post has been edited" would at least add a bit more context. Also, maybe if people knew that their first version *would* live on, they'd actually review it a bit more carefully before posting - which would be a great thing for the site in general, reducing time wasted by people asking questions without checking they make sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet because this is only in the grace period, people reading the page will see the banner, "an edit has been made to this post; click to load", even when there is no record left. I use it myself, when I'm like, "Did I really post thay instead of that?", I fix it, then see another. Without the grace period, I'd be bumping my post to the top again and again. I suppose you could say 'just be more careful', but the thing is, you often don't catch something til after you post.

Comment: @J.Musser: They'll only see that if they've already loaded the post *before* the change, won't they? While there will always be *some* things that you won't catch until after posting, an awful lot of the ones I see *really* should be caught beforehand. I get the feeling that most people asking questions don't take nearly as long as they should when doing so, not appreciating that it's more appropriate for them to spend five minutes of their time checking than it is for 10 people to waste a minute each on a bad question.

Comment: Yes @JonSkeet, only if they load the page before the change. If they first load the page after it's edited, it doesn't concern them at all, why would they need to know? I agree, though, most people could spend more time getting it right the first time.

Comment: I think that a big part of why this was initially implemented is because of how Community Wiki used to work - if these edits counted towards CW status it would have been very discouraging to editors.

Comment: @J.Musser: They need to know because the comments don't make sense, and look like the commenters can't read. From my first comment here: "so that the OP's mistake doesn't end up looking like others weren't reading properly"

Comment: A much more problematic issue that this grace period enables is shenanigans among people who are rushing to answer a question. Those who post crap answers that they turn into correct answers by relying on other people's correct answers can hide their crap in the grace period and can rely on the time stamp of their initial submission to claim that they produced the correct answer first. Having the initial and perhaps embarrassing mistakes in my posts be available for examination is a cross I'm absolutely willing to bear if it means taking the steam out of these poseurs.

Comment: Seems like the clean solution would be to just end the grace period as soon as someone posts a comment (or answer) then, @Jon.

Comment: @Shog9: Yes, I'd *definitely* be in favour of that.

Comment: @Shog9: Stack-overflow's live preview functionality isn't always accurate; it's not uncommon to have a post either fine in preview (or as good as can be expected) then hit "Submit", and then realize that it needs to be changed to appear properly in the normal view.  Hitting "submit" and then hoping a post shows up right, editing, hitting "submit" and hoping the changes fixed things, etc. is icky, but I don't know a better alternative.

Comment: @Louis: "A much more problematic issue that this grace period enables is shenanigans among people who are rushing to answer a question" -- while I agree this comes up too often, it's only driven by and/or a big concern to those who are looking at the very newest questions and rushing to try to answer to boost their rep. A _good_, thorough answer to a good question usually takes longer than five minutes to produce, so even if someone rushes, gets a bunch of edits in, they still won't produce a _good_ answer. The effect you mention exists, is annoying, but probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: That's done. @Jon.

Comment: @supercat, Either way 5 minutes is too long. Alot can happen within 5 minutes. The "realize I've made a typo right after clicking submit" can be fixed within 30 seconds, or 1 minute max.

Comment: @Pacerier: Sometimes it can take more than five minutes to fix formatting problems.  I've more often had trouble with the SE music or chess sites, but sometimes SO can pose problems when its code-formatting features mis-identify the language and highlight the wrong keywords.

Comment: @supercat, You should use stackedit. Everyone's using it these days.

Comment: your ignisecond link is not working (and I wanted to know what that was!)

Answer (score 12):

It's because people who have fat fingers or habitually commit grammar/spelling mistakes have the right to be forgiven as long as they are quick to fix their own errors.

Also the main purpose of revision history is not to nail people who accidentally make mistakes - those mistakes are the ones that would normally be fixed during the grace period.

Answer (score 8):

The grace period gives the possibility of quickly removing something, that should never be posted. For example, someone posts a code fragment that is causing problem, and he/she forgets to remove the information enabling to identify the client/company, for example package names. Or the code containing authorization credentials. Or the OP has forgotten he is not allowed to publish some information. Or anything similar.

Without grace period, that information would be visible to anyone who has rights to see edit revisions, until a moderator could handle it.

Comment: I wonder if it would be difficult to add a feature to show exactly how something would look if posted (the preview isn't always 100% accurate) but without actually committing to posting it?