# Was the 5 minute edit grace period removed?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

I just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210902/combine-divs-with-percentage-width-with-margin-in-pixels/29210957#29210957) at `2015-03-23 13:02:50Z`, and then edited it at `2015-03-23 13:07:03Z`.

This edit was made within the 5 minute grace-period (4 minutes and 13 seconds after the question was answered). Yet the edit is shown in [the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29210957/revisions).

I also just noticed that a similar thing happened [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29212025/revisions). In the linked revision, you will see that the question was answered and then edited 3 minutes and 3 seconds later... and the edit is shown in the revisions.

Was the 5 minute grace period removed?

Comment: See [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted)

Comment: @bluefeet Ahh.. Thanks - that's it. I didn't see anything on *this* meta.

Comment: Stop travelling so fast! Speed kills!

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The grace period has *not* been removed. However, it *will* end early in a couple of new scenarios. The altered behavior follows from [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285709/why-do-we-have-an-edit-grace-period) and [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted):

> Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous
>   revision was created by the same author and *none* of the following
>   conditions are present:
>
> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - **A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone *other than* the editor.**
> - **An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision**
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback

(**bold** indicates new behavior)

The intent is to allow the grace period to serve its intended purpose (quiet, painless corrections) without the confusion that occasionally results when quick edits invalidate answers or commentary.

Comment: "An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision" does that only apply to questions or also to competing answers?

Comment: @CodesInChaos It is hard to answer an answer, and I think "the post" refers to the post being edited.  To quote Shog9 elsewhere, "figure out how to post an answer to it, grace period ends" -- an answer to an answer would end that answer's grace period, but an answer to a different post (say the question the answer is answering) shouldn't be relevant.  (wonder what the SO engine would do if there was an answer to an answer?)

Comment: "and _none_ of the following conditions are present" could be replaced with "unless" and it would make my brain hurt a lot less.

Comment: @JLRishe: You'd need to replace it with more than just that. One possibility: "...unless *any* of the following conditions are present".

Comment: I mostly just translated the code into English here, @JLRishe; if you think you can state this more clearly, then feel free to edit.

Comment: It does not include competing answers, @canon - that would be weird, and wouldn't really *prevent* anything.

Comment: Unless there wasn't. Absence of evidence is not the evidence of absence and all that; if someone's *setting out* to be malicious, these things are easy to work around; most folks don't even bother trying, and those that do tend to trip themselves up in other ways. I'm not interested in breaking the system in weird, unpredictable ways for everyone to chase down a few people who are better off elsewhere anyway.

Comment: You should probably update the [editing FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) (and possibly http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info as well) instead of leaving the new rules buried here on SO and in those feature requests.

Comment: I made that FAQ cw for a reason, @jason...

Comment: @Shog9 Then please confirm my changes there. More importantly, it is probably a good idea to keep "new feature = update FAQ" in the back of your mind in general (also, since that feature was rolled out only 3 days ago, if anything changes in the near future I'll try my best to monitor, but you're the best equipped to update the FAQ). The existence of a growing divergence between the FAQ and reality could indicate a larger systemic issue.