# Did 'Edit Grace' period just fail on me?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

I am aware that if you edit your answer after 5 minutes then the answer shows the edit history.

I am also aware of the reasons mentioned in the thread [Was the 5 minute edit grace period removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288557/was-the-5-minute-edit-grace-period-removed)

However as far as I can see and I may be wrong but none of the above hold true in the question [Create data validation list when some of the values have commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724178/create-data-validation-list-when-some-of-the-values-have-commas)

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Two comments were added before your edit... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288557/was-the-5-minute-edit-grace-period-removed/288559#288559

Comment: Thank you shog but that post says "A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision". There was no previous revision. Or is my understanding of the word "Revision" is incorrect in this case?

Comment: Revision can also refer to the initial creation.

Comment: So I did misunderstand the word "Revision" Here. What would you suggest I do here? Should I just delete the question or VTC as Duplicate?

Comment: Your call; if you keep it, you might try for a more explicit title.

Comment: `Saying this in Humor (And not being sarcastic) :` From the downvotes I can clearly confirm that the English word "Revision" certainly has a different meaning in stackoverflow... :D

Comment: Revision in programmer-speak definitely includes the first.  Thank version control software.  See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632165/svn-how-to-get-the-first-revision-of-a-file), or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Comment: @Joe: I am aware what it means in programming language but we are not talking about programming here ;) we are talking about normal posts in a forum. I know we can get into a long debate on this so let's leave it at that... :)

Comment: " but we are not talking about programming here" - We are /always/ talking about programming here, even when we aren't.

Comment: @Shog9: Well, the initial creation is just revision 0, isn't it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout SO is not a forum! ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Revision can also refer to the initial creation. –  Shog9♦ 9 mins ago

I thank Shog9 for clearing my confusion in this particular scenario which also answers my question.

The answer is one of the reasons mentioned in the thread [Was the 5 minute edit grace period removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288557/was-the-5-minute-edit-grace-period-removed)

> A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.

My understanding of the word "revision" is the same as [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/revision):

> #### revision
>
> *noun*
>
> - the act of revising. ("the scheme needs drastic revision")
> - a revised edition or form of something ("a revision of the Hegelian concept of history")

However, on Stack Overflow it also counts any edits after the post was first created.

Comment: If you clicked on that "edited 46 seconds ago" in your screenshot, and put your mouse over the large "1" and "2" in the revision history, you could have determined this yourself.

Comment: Technically, you most likely *had* revised the very first version of your post before submitting it. It's just that we never got to see the first draft because you never posted it. You typed something, then perhaps noticed a mistake and corrected it, or realised you forgot to mention something and added it. So what you ended up posting was the very first *revision* of your question. Unless, of course you are a genius who never needs to edit their thoughts :)