# Is it possible for a question to be changed without any indication of an edit?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, grace-period

Going through the review queue for first posts, I have stumbled upon an unusual (for me) case.

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52175674/5366641) has two answers, both of which explain about a typo in the code. However, such code does not exist in the text. The problem is, that there is no indication that the question has been edited.

The answers have been posted almost simultaneously, so I assume they are both dealing with this "dissapeared" code in the original post, instead of copying something from each other.

Furthermore, there is a comment posted by the author of one of the answers, expressing an astonishment by the fact that the question has changed.

Is this possible or it goes about a bug?

Comment: It is possible. You have a grace period after posting where the edit won't be shown in revision (5 minutes, IIRC). Try it out on your question now, by changing a small thing, and you should be able to see the revision history doesn't change

Comment: @Patrice, That makes sense. And I almost started to believe in ghosts. :) Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: I never said ghosts don't exist. DON'T MISQUOTE ME! (joke, obviously)

Comment: :) I got it. By the way, would you mind to add this as an answer. I've looked for this before posting and wasn't able to find anything asked this way, so although rare, it might be helpful to someone else too.

Comment: Shog was able, by adding the "grace-period" tag, to highlight the best of duplicates to your question : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288557/was-the-5-minute-edit-grace-period-removed  I think this makes more sense than me posting another answer, no? I think your post makes sense as a duplicate, since the words "grace-period" might not be the ones people look for when faced with this

Comment: Kinda the opposite of that scenario, @Patrice: in this case, the edit snuck in *just prior* to the answers being posted, and thus the grace period didn't end early enough to clarify the situation. Fortunately, Google has our backs: see my answer.

Comment: In any case, the grace-period, although now perfectly logical, was not the first thing, which came to my mind.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yup. The question was edited within minutes of being posted, thus [disappearing into the grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work/21789#21789); the original revision lasted long enough for the answerers to see it and compose their answers, but disappeared just prior to the answers being posted.

Google's diligent spider captured the original version of the page, which you may still be able to view [in its cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KqqZdRMXBQoJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175674/browse-an-external-web-page-inside-of-an-iframe):

[image: iframe linking to miencraftservers.org, followed by: "So basically I am trying to make this iframe show up on a page on my website and have people be able to click on things inside of it, but they can't scroll or do anything inside it, is this possible?"]

Comment: @Patrice and Shog9, thank you for your time and explanations!

Comment: I am astonished that Google managed to crawl the page within minutes of it appearing; I wonder if it's a coincidence or if it aggressively refreshes a landing page and follows all new links.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I’m very sure that Google has web site refresh priorities which result in certain important sites getting scanned in minute intervals.