# Could we please stop punishing answerers when questions get closed

Tags: feature-request, answers, closed-questions

So I've just been answering a question, and just as I'm finishing up my answer, I get the following pop up, and am unable to submit my answer.

> This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted.

If this happens once in isolation, it's not too bad, but this keeps happening to me, and I've spent a lot of time authoring carefully crafted, thoughtful answers, just for the entire effort to be wasted.

As you can imagine, this is very frustrating, and a very poor user experience.  I even stopped contributing to the site altogether for quite some time because of this problem.

Could we please allow any in-progress answers to be finished and posted rather than punish the answerers for any perceived flaws in the question.

At the moment, any time anyone answers a question, they play Russian roulette, and could have their effort thrown away at a moments notice.

You can mitigate this by submitting a quick incomplete answer, and then editing it to improve it, but this is not always acceptable, and IMO is a poor practice to mitigate a very poor UX.

Comment: Isn't there a 15-minutes grace period to finish up and post the answer after the question has been closed?

Comment: Not that I've ever observed.  The banner came up, and the post button was disabled immediately.

Comment: Correction, 5 minutes, but could be overridden https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288559/584192

Comment: If that's true, 5 minutes is not long enough to finish a high quality answer.

Comment: If this keeps happening to you, I suggest you stop trying to answer off-topic or low-quality questions.

Comment: @Stijn, I knew someone was going to say that.  Have you ever considered that some of those people are the ones who need the most help?

Comment: While I understand and sympathize with frustration, making it easier to add answers to otherwise closable questions seems counterproductive for the site, if more lenient with good intentioned users.

Comment: @DoctorJones: SO is (or should be) not that much about helping single users. Either they ask a clear, concise question that will help a large number of people, or they are in the wrong place.

Comment: If you allow in-progress answers to be completed, you're not exactly going to "open the floodgates".  You do however stop a very frustrating user experience.  It's not nice spending a whole bunch of time on an answer, just to have that effort thrown away.  It's not even as if you can then PM the OP and give it to them directly.

Comment: It's not about helping individual users, that's a collateral benefit. You can try steering users to chat for that, through comments for example. It might be more suitable.

Comment: Yeah @Bdl, that's the big problem with SO.  That's why we had the "not very welcoming" issue.  It's funny how a QA site has skewed it's objectives so much, that it's no longer about actually helping people.

Comment: @DoctorJones People asking low quality questions might need help, but not from here. Here is for high quality questions only. The fact that the askers still need help is irrelevant. The mission of this site is to make high quality QA, not to help everyone including people who can't or won't ask a clear and concise question. That's why it's even successful. If you want unfettered access to answerers, well quora is right over there, and the quality shows that.

Comment: @DoctorJones: You got me wrong. SO is about helping people. But not in the sense of a personal helpdesk for every user. What SO always aimed to do is to build a knowledge base of high-quality questions and answers that help a lot of people.

Comment: No, as @yivi so eloquently put, helping people is a "collateral benefit", i.e. not the main goal.  That's not how I see it, but that's the general culture here.  I aim to help the person on the other side of the keyboard, and in turn, also help any future visitiors.  I've seen way to many questions closed as a duplicate of a question that is a poor fit.  We wouldn't do that if we had our priorities in order.  The most useful questions get the most traffic anyway, so it doesn't matter if a question is closed, or remains open and gets very few page views.

Comment: @DoctorJones So this boils down that you disagree what the site's priorities should be. Fair enough, but I'm unsure you'll ever affect change there.

Comment: @Doctor I didn't mean "helping people" is a collateral benefit, but helping **individual users**. You are helping all the future programmers that come looking for this knowledge. That the asker got helped along the way? That's a bonus. Apparently you want to use the site the other way around. It's not a huge surprise it can be frustrating now and then.

Comment: @Magisch, no, this boils down to the fact that I spent a good 20 minutes answering a question, and having my effort thrown away by poor UX driven by questionable ideals.

Comment: @DoctorJones for your latest attempt at posting an answer, the question was closed as a duplicate. Unless you disagree with the given duplicate, the system is working as intended.

Comment: You can always *post a new, high quality question* to post that answer to. It is not lost, you have the text right there to reuse elsewhere. If the question was closed as a duplicate, perhaps your answer is worth moving to the canonical, if it is of such high quality.

Comment: And if one disagrees with a dupe closure, the way to actually help the asker is to help them edit the question so it's no longer a duplicate, and/or is better explained **why** it isn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, as things stand, the system does this by design, and anyone that falls foul of it has a terrible experience.  It's a problem that people should be aware of, and they should also be very aware of how it makes the end user feel, i.e. frustrated, enraged and defeated.  Is that how good UX is supposed to make a user feel?

Comment: Again, I understand the frustration. But at no point in those 20' you had enough interaction with the asker and the question to get an inkling that the question could get closed? Comments? Close votes? If it was very suddenly closed by gold tag holder, and there was absolutely no activity on the question... well. It could happen. But it shouldn't be happening you very often.

Comment: @DoctorJones: then come up with UI that still won’t let you post the answer. We put questions on hold **explicitly** to prevent answers being posted. We are not going to prevent closure if there are answers in flight or allow answers that have been started to be posted anyway. That goes counter to the goals that have made SO a success.

Comment: Looks like [this is the question you're trying to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213621/c-sharp-new-virtual-method-and-as-is-casts). Is there any reason why you don't answer it on the duplicate... or challenge the close if it's really not a duplicate?

Comment: I want to make a reference to my [cabinet castle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378863/1197934) here.  Closing a question is giving the cabinet back, for some reason; it's not strong enough to hold up in the wall, so it needs to be fixed.  Doing otherwise will cause an eventual collapse of the wall, and that's generally bad for *everybody*.  Keeping the castle standing is more important than allowing every cabinet a place in the castle.

Comment: Hm. Maybe take a break from Stack Overflow or you may be heading to a burnout. There are plenty of websites where you can provide direct assistance to people. Or you can try, it's a very hit and miss process. More miss than hit, to be honest. Frequent endless back-and-forth sessions that tire you out. If it is not that then you will find that you are answering the same questions repeatedly and frequently. It's more satisfying to maintain the Stack Overflow repository so *people can successfully help themselves*, IMO.

Comment: _"I even stopped contributing to the site altogether for quite some time because of this problem."_ Hmm, I stopped contributing to the site altogether for quite some time because of the problem that too many questions that should be closed are getting answered instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robert Cartaino (a Stack Exchange employee) opened a discussion for a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange responding to this issue: [Tell answer-author when the question is being voted to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322503)

> When I am in the editor writing an answer to a question, the system will notify me (in real time!) when another answer has been posted. This is presumably so I can see if the new answer may have rendered my post somewhat redundant.
>
> **Can we extend that same feature/courtesy to authors when a question is being voted to close?**

Feel free to chime in on the discussion constructively!

Comment: I'm glad something constructive has come out of this.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 34):

> At the moment, any time anyone answers a question, they play Russian
>   roulette, and could have their effort thrown away at a moments notice.

That's only true if you pick questions you answer indiscriminately. Poor, unclear or otherwise deficient questions get closed. High quality interesting questions do not. So if you focus on answering those, you will rarely if ever encounter this problem.

> Could we please allow any in-progress answers to be finished and
>   posted rather than punish the answerers for any perceived flaws in the
>   question.

That's the wrong angle on it. If a question is closed, that says that it is *unanswerable* for the purposes of SO Q/A. So, for instance, if a tool recommendation question is closed that is because we do not want answers just recommending tools to it. If a unclear question is closed that is because we do not want answers just wildly guessing, etc... .

> If this happens once in isolation, it's not too bad, but this keeps
>   happening to me, and I've spent a lot of time authoring carefully
>   crafted, thoughtful answers, just for the entire effort to be wasted.

If this keeps happening to you, you need to be more discerning in which questions you choose to answer. Yes, that is not the reputation-maximizing strategy, but after all we want to build a lasting high quality Q/A experience here, not just play free helpdesk for everyone.

Comment: "If a question is closed, that says that it is unanswerable" either unanswerable or the answers posted to it would not be very useful, as is the case for the examples you gave.

Comment: @Servy And this is so, [even if the question has an *accepted* answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable)

Answer (score 15):

> Could we please allow any in-progress answers to be finished and posted rather than punish the answerers for any perceived flaws in the question.

No. To the extent that what you're talking about constitutes "punishment", such users *deserve* to be punished.

Users of this site are expected to answer on-topic, well-written, properly-scoped questions. Users who answer low-quality, poorly-stated, ill-conceived, or otherwise bad questions are harming the site by that action. Users who do bad things (even with good intent) should expect sanctioning (again, to the extent that stopping someone from answering a bad question is "punishment").

Such actions harm the site. They give the impression that this site is intended to support those questions, and would do so if some small clique of users would just stop closing them. So if on occasion, users who perform those actions have their time wasted by preventing them from doing things we don't want them doing... so be it.

And yes, sometimes the question isn't bad so much as a duplicate (though dupes can be bad too). And given SO's crappy search, I can understand why you wouldn't want to waste your time trying to find the duplicate. But, given that, if the question is closed as a dupe, then the OP still gets an answer. Yes, you lost the time you spent writing your answer, but the OP got what they needed. So just accept that the OP was helped and move on.

Comment: I get what you're trying to say, but please more specifically spell this out: nobody is ever punished on this site, it's just a website. A user account may have privileges revoked. Content may be downvoted, closed and/or deleted. But that's about it. Nobody is punished. No lashes. No scolding allowed. No sending to a room. No detention. No going to bed without dessert. No jail time. Nol slap on the wrist with a ruler. No 20 pushups. No community service. No nothing. If someone feels punished by site mechanics: get another Frappuccino and cool down.

Comment: @Gimby The site does more than just downvote, close, and delete content.  It also puts restrictions on users to prevent them from asking questions if they have a history of bad contributions.  Those *are* punishments of the user as a direct consequence of their behavior, and it's an action taken against *the account*, not the content.  There are also other punishments like manual account suspensions.  How big of a deal those punishments are will vary from person to person, but they *are* punishments.  Nicol Bolas is right that *votes* aren't a punishment, but the site *does* have punishments.

Answer (score -3):

I must give a 4-letter word on the heavy objection against this proposal - GOOD!

Compliment aside, it's really frustrating when you almost finished a decent answer, and surprised to see the question gets closed as a duplicate - that's BAD. You wasted all your efforts in this answer, and your draft probably won't be useful again, or even so, it's unlikely you'll be able find it out when you feel it could be useful again.

Of course, the situation does NOT apply when you're just a rep hunter answering all the bad or blatant duplicate questions. It's not an excuse to post an answer just for rep, instead of marking it as duplicate or voting to close accordingly. I mean, sometimes I just feel the question worths answering, and have absolutely no idea it could be closed.

In rare cases like the one described above, I try to force-submit my completed answer. Read more @@>>> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316139

Comment: If you are saying that the opposition to the proposal is GOOD that means you *agree* with users who sustain that bad questions should not receive an answer, which contradicts your observation (I mean, sometimes I just feel the question worths answering, and have absolutely no idea it could be closed.) Do you agree with the naysayers/the downvoters?