# Should I be worried about a declined rude/abusive flag because the answer was edited within the grace period?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, rude-or-abusive, grace-period

I have flagged an answer as rude/abusive, because it was really rude at the time I saw it. It was something like

> You are so stupid, if you can't figure out yourself.

The answer was edited during the grace period to a more friendly text and then got deleted (likely "not an answer").

[image: deleted question]

I'm a bit worried regarding my flag history, since this this is the third time, a rude/abusive flag got declined. I really rarely use it (3 times in 6 years) but I have a 100% decline rate for these kinds of flags.

[image: Rude flags]

Should I just ignore this and continue as usual? Would having too many declined flags result in any penalties?

Comment: It literally does not matter one iota if you have 2 or 3 declined flags. Especially when you have hundreds of flags marked helpful.

Comment: It was edited during the [grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288559/11682469)? You could monitor the post a bit and retract the flag if they change it. In general (since you had other declined R/A flags), [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307385/11682469) offers useful advice - an R/A flag is not appropriate if it can be salvaged by an edit, eg. an actual answer containing expletives when they can be edited out ("this is how I got that ... method to work"), if it's only abusive or gibberish ("... everyone on ... SO" or "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"), then R/A is the way to go.

Comment: @JeanneDark: yes, it was edited during the grace period. Otherwise it would be visible in the edit history. It was rude, like "You are so stupid, if you can't figure out yourself." Not even an attempt to answer anything. I'm thinking of making a screenshot next time.

Comment: Dont worry, you wont get banned for several declined flags, if in doubt about flagging a specific post you can always ask in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: @ThomasWeller 'following' the post might also help, since it will notify the user when the post is edited :)

Comment: Ah the old chat room poke joke. Say something offensive and then quickly change it to something incredibly inoffensive before anyone has a chance to react to it and you're left wondering "wait, what did I just read?".

Comment: trick with quick comment ([explained eg here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601)) would break grace period. Although for R/A posts I personally would prefer to take a little risk and flag without commenting

Comment: I usually don't flag posts until they are out  of the grace period, as this has happened to me before.

Comment: I feel like votes and flags should break the edit grace period too, since you were reacting to the original text after all.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery this could make things a bit messy (and possibly somewhat prone to abuse) because votes and flags can be retracted

Comment: @gnat But comments can be deleted too. How would you even abuse that anyway?

Comment: Someone will find a way. Someone always finds a way. If you build it, abuse will come.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I meant to say _mis_use, sorry. As in, doing things for side effect instead of intended purpose. Commenting R/A posts for example in many cases could feel like that (maybe main reason why I prefer to abstain of it). As for deleting comments, yes, it also has some potential to be troublesome, and what makes it more acceptable to me is that writing comments tends to take more effort compared to casting flag or vote

Comment: Just hurts your feelings, nothing else ... It is worse when a [grace edit](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=26589483#26589483) is your [only declined spam flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzkZI.png) `

Comment: @JohnMontgomery One could start account 2, and with  account 2 they could write spam posts and then flag it with account 1. Then with account 2 they would edit it (within the grace period) to be a different answer that isn't spam, but perhaps NAA. Then account 1 would get a spam flag. If account 2 gets answer banned, they create a new account 2.

Comment: As I read the previous comments, I kept wondering which were (playfully) rude/abusive prior to being edited to their current form.

Comment: @kjhughes You can assume all of mine are, I just try to edit them *before* submission.

Comment: @CodyGray: Lol.  And so it seems we also have an answer to an age-old question: If a rude/abusive flag falls in the forest but no moderator reads the abuse within the grace period, declining the flag ***does*** make a sound ... on Meta.

Comment: This conversation just reinforces my conviction that I should stay away from flagging things or looking at queues.

Comment: Why, @BoarGules? Because mistakes sometimes happen? Because a moderator might, on occasion disagree with you? I really don't think that's enough of a reason to stay away from anything.