# Why some users remove the content before deleting their post

Tags: discussion

I've seen many users who removes the content of their post(mostly answers) before deleting the post.

They add some dummy characters like

`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

or

`======================Deleted==================`

An example of this

[image: Example]

Why do the users do this when users having reputation more than 10K can see their previous edits using *Revision History*?

Comment: To not give 10k+ users a bad idea may be.

Comment: Are you able to see the different versions of the post?

Comment: It's an alternative to deleting the content before posting, (a much better choice in many cases:).

Comment: Because sometimes you make a really stupid mistake when interpreting the question, which causes you to post an embarrassing answer. Hopefully you catch it before the grace period and can edit it all out as to not show users > 10k how stupid you can be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**People mess up**

This often happens if someone posts an answer then quickly realizes that it was wrong and they don't want people to see how bad they dun goofed.

**Looks like that's what happened here**

And according to your comment in the screenshot, I would presume this is exactly what happened here. The author was pointed out that they missed something in the OP and that their answer was incorrect and maybe even way off.

**We don't like people to see that we are fallible**

It basically just saves some face for 10k+ers who could see the deleted post. If it is edited within the grace period (don't recall off-hand what it is, maybe 5 minutes) then there is no revision history.

**Sometimes just a band-aid in case people are too lazy/uncaring to look at history**

If it isn't done within the grace period then appropriate users could still see the revision history but they probably feel this is better than leaving it in the open. I know I've done it once or twice when I completely misread a question or was thinking wrong and put something completely absurd (I blame lack of coffee in those moments).

As [Martin James points out in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303036/why-some-users-remove-the-content-before-deleting-their-post#comment236772_303036) besides not looking incompetent/wrong this can be helpful because it lets people know that the author realized they messed up and to ignore the post. I know I often still look at deleted posts out of curiosity or whatever it may be. But this can be distracting. When users do this, it tells me that there's no need to pay any attention to it whatsoever.

So it doesn't get lost in the comments because I think it's a great point...

[Jon points out that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303036/why-some-users-remove-the-content-before-deleting-their-post/303037#comment236781_303037)

> Also - some consider it a courtesy when deleting a fairly large post to edit content out first so that it doesn't occupy so much screen space for 10k users.

Comment: Seems legit, but that does imply you know how SO works which is usually not the case for SO novices. In forums it is a common practice to empty a question because you're not actually allowed to delete them; it is the only way you can save face / act out in anger / hide your cheating from your teacher. I'm wondering if for SO novices this is more caused by discovering they can delete it only after they hastily deface.

Comment: @Gimby It's possible but I don't know who posted the example given so couldn't say if they are an experienced SO-ian or not. And I typically only notice this from more seasoned users and not newer members. Either way, it's not a problem unless someone is doing it quite often in which case, the system will see that they are deleting often.

Comment: Also - some consider it a courtesy when deleting a fairly large post to edit content out first so that it doesn't occupy so much screen space for 10k users.

Comment: @JonClements But after you posted an answer to SO it's part of Stack Overflow and adds more or less value to it. So shouldn't we **theoretically** roll it back, since they "destroy" their own content even if it is deleted?!

Comment: @codeMagic If they do that only to *"save their faces"*, then I'm asking myself what they are going to do if they mess up in the real world where they can't run away and delete it :]

Comment: @Rizer [Somewhat related to your first comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285714/1380752) why keep something around that the author quickly realizes was a mistake and completely unhelpful. To your second point, "saving face" isn't the *only* reason but I think a major one. And, what's the big deal? Do you ever mess up then fix it quickly before anyone can notice (now or in the future)?

Comment: @codeMagic If it is a small problem and I can fix it quickly I do. But if I have the responsibility for something and there is a bigger problem, you can't just hide in the real world (And write something like: `===delete===`). No matter if you or someone else messed up, I have to fix it.

Comment: @codeMagic "And I typically only notice this from more seasoned users and not newer members" - I'm actually glad to read that, it makes your more positive spin on this all the more likely.