# Prevent third-party edits during the grace period

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, grace-period

I recently posted an answer containing a code example. Immediately after posting, I realized that the code could be improved and simplified with a little refactoring. I hastened to write and test the new code, so I could update the answer within the 5 minute grace period. I was successful, sort of.

The problem is that within those 5 minutes, a low rep user decided to improve the formatting of the introduction, and made a suggested edit. That edit may or may not have been a good one, but I rejected it, because I didn't have the time to evaluate the changes, and merge them with my changes. The unfortunate side effect is that the person suggesting the edit may have hurt feelings from the experience.

Note that I've been on the other side as well. I've seen typos in answers, and tried to edit, only to have the edits overridden because the OP was editing at the same time.

So my suggestion is that questions/answers should be locked (only editable by the OP) during the grace period. That allows the OP time to review/improve/finalize their post before opening the post to public review and editing.

---

Edit: For reference, see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285714/3386109) on why we have a grace period.

Comment: @Kendra I almost never use the grace period. In fact, I rarely edit my posts. I always write the posts off-line, review/edit/test and then post. As a result, I'm almost never the FGITW. In the case in point, my answer was the fourth answer posted.

Comment: @user3386109 So then you don't actually have a compelling reason to lock the post from editing, as you're virtually never editing your posts after posting them.

Comment: @Servy My compelling reason was to avoid wasting the time of people simultaneously editing the post in the first five minutes. The grace period worked fine for me in this case. The person who was hurt was the low rep user that spent time improving the post, only to have their edit overridden by my edit.

Comment: I realized after posting it that my comment would make a decent answer for this, so I've moved it there and expanded it a bit. The fact that you only want this to not waste editor time doesn't seem a like a great argument for this feature, to me. To be honest, there's a good chance the user may not even ever realize their edit didn't go through, depending on how new to the site they are and how much time they've spent learning the site mechanics. If they don't think to check it, they may even forget they suggested an edit to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you are usually not the FGTIW I guess this particular situation won't happen very often.

Here is what I suggest in these cases:

You could have taken even a bit of time, evaluate the changes, accept the suggested edit if it is good, merge the changes with your changes and deliver an even more improved post with a bit of delay.

Or, you could have rejected the edit but keep the tab open, apply your changes, then take the time to analyze the suggested edit and merge it if it is good but give attribution in that case. The +2 rep for the editer is lost but you didn't loose time and at least the content of the edit is not lost.

I would not like that a suggested edit is just thrown away. The two ways described above circumvent this.

Comment: Thanks, next time someone suggests an edit, I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 6):

I see a couple of issues with this particular suggestion.

First, not everyone uses the grace period to review their posts. I wouldn't be surprised to find out that most users don't even know about the grace period for a post.

With this in mind, I would also not be surprised to find this change leaving posts that *could* be good with some edits as not-so-good posts for five minutes. Depending on how many eyes it gets in that five minutes, the post could be downvoted, closed if it's a question, or even deleted by the time the grace period was up. Meanwhile, some interested user like myself is waiting for the grace period to expire to try to save this post that they see promise in.*

Second, these reviews of your post should ideally be done *before* you submit the post and the grace period should only be there in the off-chance of a minor typo or two. Proofreading a few times never hurts, nor does testing your code one more time. I'm not saying you don't do this, nor am I saying you can't still miss things doing this, but that is the ideal situation. Because of this, it *should* be more of an edge case that you're trying to improve your post in the grace period and someone else submits an edit. I would be interested in how frequently this situation occurs, as that could make more of an argument for or against the feature-request.

While I don't see the second issue as nearly as big an potential problem as the first, it *is* still something to consider. But with the first situation to consider, I think this could be potentially harmful to the community and may cause more harm than good.

---

<sup><sub>* I realize this is probably not an extremely common occurrence in and of itself, but I can imagine plenty of situations where a question could be closed as "unclear" within five minutes, and could have been saved with a quick edit by an interested third party.</sub></sup>

Comment: *"I would be interested in how frequently this situation occurs, as that could make more of an argument for or against the feature-request."* That's a good point. It would be useful to have the stats on 1) suggested edits, 2) high rep edits, 3) OP edits, 4) edit conflicts within the grace period.

Comment: It would indeed. If this happened with, say, 1 in 20 posts then that would be a much better argument for the feature. But if it happens more like 1 in 8k posts... That'd average out to around once a day, and I feel on a site of this size that wouldn't be worth it at all to implement this.

Comment: Well here's one stat from [the post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285714/3386109) I linked: *"something like 20% of answers are edited at least once during the grace period."*

Comment: Which is a great starting point, but that doesn't tell us what I would find to be more important: How many edits are made/suggested by other users in that time, and how many edits are reverted by the OP trying to edit in the grace period.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It occurs to me that I probably shouldn't have generalized the request to include questions. My focus was on answers, but  I threw questions into the mix without fully considering the ramifications. You make a good case that questions should be editable in the first 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Ninja-editing (editing your post immediately after posting without the changes being visible) is a thing all over the web. On almost every site where user-generated content is used, users can edit their posts, and a lot of those sites use a grace period during which it is not shown that edits were made to said post.

I think editors should be aware of this. Editors should not try to fix posts when they were posted only a short period before; they should anticipate that the poster is still looking at the post and are trying to improve it themselves.

So no, don't block edits. Only *if* this proves to be a common problem (which I highly doubt), a notice could be displayed to editors, like *"This post was posted very recently; chances are the poster is still working on it. If you spot an error, consider leaving a comment instead"*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was thinking along the lines of disabling the `edit` link for all but the OP during the first 5 minutes. But of course, we would first have to agree that edits should be blocked.